# React Native - Defining types for FlatList Ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a problem with Eslint complaining about "unsafe call on any type" and I have to give a type to FlatList Ref.

```
  const flatListRef = useRef(null);
```

So unsafe call coming from this piece of code ;

```
  flatListRef?.current?.scrollToOffset // <---- here
```

Typescript can't see the scrollToOffset apparently, how can I tell typescript that this is a FlatList ref ? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `const flatListRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);`

Answer (score 0):

Simply use:

```
const flatlistRef = useRef<FlatList>(null);
```